# How can I parse a value to show as an integer in a razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have

```
    @{
    var to = Model.PageMeta.TestID == "00" ? "All Tests" : Model.PageMeta.TestID;
    }
```

The value of TestID can be "00","01","02" etc

What I would like to do is display this as "All Tests", "1", "2" etc.  In other words I want to just show the value without the leading zero.

I tried

```
parseInt(Model.PageMeta.TestID)
```

but this gave me a compiler error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [`Int32.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) method.

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0173: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'int'

Comment: Whats the value that is being passed as parameter to Int32.Parse() method. For e.g. Int32.Parse("1") returns 1. Instead of Int32.Parse, you can use Int32.TryParse and see if the imput string can be parsed into a integer or not.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do that would be to use [TrimStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx)

Comment: Thats no good as it will trim "00" to string.Empty, use myint = Convert.ToInt32(variable). Edit: Nvm, it would work for this, but for other cases where you'd want to have 0 it wouldn't work

Comment: @Serge yeah I caught that right after I added my comment, its still better to use Convert as you'll get a valid integer that way which is the main question the OP was asking.

Answer (score 0):

If its a string, use [Convert.ToInt32()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx)

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            string s = "00";
            string s2 = "04";

            int i = Convert.ToInt32(s);
            int i2 = Convert.ToInt32(s2);

            Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", i, i2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0|4
```

Compared to TrimStart:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            string s = "00";
            string s2 = "04";

            Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", s.TrimStart('0'), s2.TrimStart('0'));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
|4
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the simplest but most complete would be this:

```
 @{
 var to = Model.PageMeta.TestID == "00" ? 
  "All Tests" : 
         (Model.PageMeta.TestID.StartsWith("0") ? 
                 Model.PageMeta.TestID.Substring(1) : 
                 Model.PageMeta.TestID);
  }
```